# Automating a mount operation that requires user input

Tags: mount, 16.04, fstab, webdav, davfs2

I want to mount a directory on a file server at startup. This is my */etc/fstab* entry:

```
# mount the fileserver
https://fsrv.company/ /mnt/fileserver davfs user,auto 0 0
```

Manually mounting it with `mount /mnt/fileserver` works fine. However, because of an outdated certificate this issues a prompt which I always have to answer with yes:

```
/sbin/mount.davfs: the server certificate does not match the server name
/sbin/mount.davfs: the server certificate is not trusted
[...]
Accept certificate for this session? [y,N] y
```

This device should be mounted when starting Ubuntu (due to the `auto` option). However, the device is not mounted, probably because of the required input. The owner of the fileserver wont update its certificate.

How can I automate this process, such that the device is mounted at startup with the answer being always `y\n`?

EDIT: I did download and place the certificate in *.davfs2/certs/* and edited the entry in *.davfs2/davfs2.conf* (as hinted below by @Oli), but the interactive input remains.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my case I used the code highlighted by [Oli](https://askubuntu.com/a/488817/202422) above and then used the [trust_server_cert](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/man5/davfs2.conf.5.html) option in the dav2fs config.

> Usefull  when  the  server's certificate can't be verified or is
>                 even invalid, but you know that you can trust this  certificate.

So edit `/etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf` and add a line that looks like the following:

```
trust_server_cert        /etc/davfs2/certs/my.selfsigned.cert.pem
```

This allowed me to mount a self-signed OwnCloud webdav even when the certificate host didn't match.

Comment: Meanwhile, this is a clean solution provided by newer versions of davfs. Instead of listing all certificates as `servercert`, it distinguishes `trust_ca_cert` and `trust_server_cert`.

Comment: Thanks jotrocken, I was running davfs2 1.4.7 which doesn't support `trust_server_cert`.  I might have to compile from the source code. Latest version is 1.5.4 at the time of this comment.

Answer (score 5):

Wouldn't it just be easier to fix the trust issue and install the certificate?

1. Download the certificate (thanks to [elec3647](https://superuser.com/users/245449/elec3647) [on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/641396/30127))

   ```
   openssl s_client -connect HOSTNAME:443 -showcerts </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -outform PEM > certificate.pem
   ```
2. Copy the certificate to `/etc/davfs2/certs/`

   ```
   sudo cp certificate.pem /etc/davfs2/certs/
   ```

That should deal with the problem directly.

Comment: You are right, this is the straight-forward way. Which fails because of `/sbin/mount.davfs: the server certificate does not match the server name`. This is why I need a workaround. Will edit this above.

Comment: Thank you! Finally an example that worked.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of solving this would be changing the CN (identity) of the server certificate to set it to your domain (in this case `fsrv.company`).

However you can get around this by doing it the ghetto way, add a command to the boot (on Ubuntu that would be Startup Applications for example) with the following:

`echo y | mount /mnt/fileserver`

This will basically 'auto-accept' the error in the certificate for you.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem but I found a different solution. I simply installed the ca-certificates package, because my certificate was signed by an official CA : Terena.

```
/sbin/mount.davfs: the server certificate is not trusted
  issuer:      TERENA, Amsterdam, Noord-Holland, NL
  subject:     Domain Control Validated
  identity:    owncloud-mshe.univ-fcomte.fr
  fingerprint: 0e:5f:b4:02:c2:a7:d7:7f:8b:ef:9c:06:25:0c:c0:1f:d4:38:83:1d
```

The solution is :

```
apt install ca-certificates
```